# What is the purpose of OpenGL texture buffer objects?

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

We use buffer objects for reducing copy operations from CPU-GPU and for texture buffer objects we can change target from vertex to texture in buffer objects. Is there any other advantage here of texture buffer objects? Also, it does not allow filtering, is there any disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A buffer texture is similar to a 1D-texture but has a backing buffer store that's *not* part of the texture object (in contrast to any other texture object) but realized with an actual buffer object bound to `TEXTURE_BUFFER`. Using a buffer texture has several implications and, AFAIK, one use-case that can't be mapped to any other type of texture.

Note that a buffer texture is *not* a buffer object - a buffer texture is merely associated with a buffer object using [glTexBuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexBuffer).

By comparison, buffer textures can be huge. Table 23.53 and following of the core OpenGL 4.4 spec defines a minimum maximum (i.e. the minimal value that implementations must provide) number of *texels* `MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE`. The potential number of texels being stored in your buffer object is computed as follows (as found in [GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_buffer_object.txt)):

`floor(<buffer_size> / (<components> * sizeof(<base_type>))`

The resulting value clamped to `MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE` is the number of addressable texels.

**Example:**

You have a buffer object storing 4MiB of data. What you want is a buffer texture for addressing RGBA texels, so you choose an internal format `RGBA8`. The addressable number of texels is then

`floor(4MiB / (4 * sizeof(UNSIGNED_BYTE)) == 1024^2 texels == 2^20 texels`

If your implementation supports this number, you can address the full range of values in your buffer object. The above isn't too impressive and can simply be achieved with any other texture on current implementations. However, the machine on which I'm writing this answer supports `2^28 == 268435456` texels.

With OpenGL 4.4 (and 4.3 and possibly with earlier 4.x versions), the `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` is 2 ^ 16 texels per 1D-texture, so a buffer texture can still be 4 times as large. On my local machine I can allocate a 2GiB buffer texture (even larger actually), but only a 1GiB 1D-texture when using `RGBAF32` texels.

A use-case for buffer textures is random (and atomic, if desired) read-/write-access (the latter via image load/store) to a large data store inside a shader. Yes, you can do random *read*-access on arrays of uniforms inside one or multiple blocks but it gets very tedious if you have to process a lot of data and have to work with multiple blocks and even then, looking at the maximum combined size of all uniform components (where a single float component has a size of 4 bytes) in all uniform blocks for a single stage,

`MAX_(stage)_UNIFORM_BLOCKS *  MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE +  MAX_(stage)_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS * 4`

isn't really a lot of space to work with in a shader stage (depending on how large your implementation allows the above number to be).

An important difference between textures and buffer textures is that the data store, as a regular buffer object, can be used in operations where a texture simply does not work. The extension mentions:

> The use of a buffer object to provide storage allows the texture data to
> be specified in a number of different ways:  via buffer object loads
> (BufferData), direct CPU writes (MapBuffer), framebuffer readbacks
> (EXT_pixel_buffer_object extension).  A buffer object can also be loaded
> by transform feedback (NV_transform_feedback extension), which captures
> selected transformed attributes of vertices processed by the GL.  Several
> of **these mechanisms do not require an extra data copy**, which would be
> required when using conventional TexImage-like entry points.

An implication of using buffer textures is that look-ups inside a shader can only be done via `texelFetch`. Buffer textures also aren't mip-mapped and, as you already mentioned, during fetches there is no filtering.

**Addendum**:

Since OpenGL 4.3, we have what is called a
[Shader Storage Buffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). These too provide random (atomic) read-/write-access to a large data store but don't need to be accessed with `texelFetch()` or image load/store functions as is the case for buffer textures. Using buffer textures also implies having to deal with `gvec4` return values, both with `texelFetch()` and `imageLoad()` / `imageStore()`. This becomes very tedious as soon as you want to work with structures (or arrays thereof) and you don't want to think of some stupid packing scheme using multiple instances of `vec4` or using multiple buffer textures to achieve something similar. With a buffer accessed as shader storage, you can simple index into the data store and pull one or more instances of some `struct {}` directly from the buffer.

Also, since they are very similar to uniform blocks, using them should be fairly straight forward - if you know how to use uniform buffers, you don't have a long way to go learn how to use shader storage buffers.

It's also absolutely worth browsing the Issues section of the corresponding [ARB extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_storage_buffer_object.txt).

**Performance Implications**

Daniel Rakos did some performance analysis years ago, both as a [comparison of uniform buffers and buffer textures](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/01/uniform-buffers-vs-texture-buffers/), and also on a little [more general](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/11/texture-and-buffer-access-performance/) note based on information from AMD's OpenCL programming guide. There is now a very recent version, specifically targeting [OpenCL optimization](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide2.pdf) an AMD platforms.

There are many factors influencing performance:

- access patterns and resulting caching behavior
- cache line sizes and memory layout
- what kind of memory is accessed (registers, local, global, L1/L2 etc.) and its respective memory bandwidth
- how well memory fetching latency is hidden by doing something else in the meantime
- what kind of hardware you're on, i.e. a dedicated graphics card with dedicated memory or some unified memory architecture
- etc., etc.

As always when worrying about performance: implement something that works and see if that solutions is fast enough for your needs. Otherwise, implement two or more approaches to solving the problem, **profile** them and compare.

Also, vendor specific guides can offer a great deal of insight. The above mentioned OpenCL user and optimization guides provide a high-level architectural perspective and specific hints on how to optimize your CL kernels - stuff that's also relevant when developing shaders.

Comment: Could you explain "A use-case for buffer textures is random-access into a data store inside a shader. This is something you can't do with uniform buffer or shader storage buffers."? I was under the impression that SSBOs were for random access into large arrays.

Comment: I'm just getting familiar with OpenGL 4 and had this question. Your answer illustrates advantages of buffer textures over other textures and uniform buffers, are there also use cases/performance differences over shader storage buffers?

Comment: @kai: I updated the answer substantially. In most cases I don't see why SSBOs should perform significantly better or worse because they essentially are simply linear arrays of data that have which have to support random access - albeit by different means. The only reason I can think of why performance would differ is that texture units, which are used to do buffer texture lookups, could possibly fetch data more efficiently but I have nothing to back that up. Try it and profile - it shouldn't take you much time to implement two approaches to the same problem.

Comment: Hmm. "A use-case for buffer textures is random (and atomic, if desired) read-/write-access [...]" - one can use a non-buffer texture for that, no? :)

Comment: "Several of these mechanisms do not require an extra data copy" - could you please say which ones?

Answer (score 1):

A one use case I have found was to store per primitive attributes (accessed in the fragment shader with help of gl_PrimitiveID) while still maintaining unique vertices in the indexed mesh.